# Core image filter's output image is nil second time it is run on a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image

I am using Core Image to apply a sepia filter to an image. I have the filter set to a tap gesture. The fist time I press the tap gesture, the filter applies to the image of an image view and I add output back to the image view. When I press the screen a second time, the app crashes and says the output is nil. Anyone know why this is happening? Code and error message image are below.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap")
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }

    func tap(){

        // 2
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: imageview.image)

        // 3
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")

        filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        imageview.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue before. There is no problem in your code. I think what's wrong is the picture you use. This basic production process without `CIContext` cannot handle picture with alpha channel. I think you may be using a picture with alpha channel such as an icon or something. Change your picture with photo and have a try again.